Filtering nested JavaScript object by an array of paths
I have an nested JavaScript object similar to this
const obj = {
  topLevelProp1: 'some',
  topLevelProp2: 'data',
  topLevelPropArr: [{
    uid: 'd7ed3623-e431-4bfa-85b3-8da14fa399c3',
    secLevelProp1: 123,
    secLevelPropArr: [{
      uid: '15562309-22b7-4b11-a12e-b3374f0a7636',
      thirdLevelProp1: 'a plain value',
      thirdLevelProp2: {
        a: 'I am',
        b: 'a nested',
        c: 'object',
      },
    }, {
      uid: '9394f313-b7bf-45fa-b8f3-683832ff7aa2',
      thirdLevelProp1: null,
      thirdLevelProp2: {
        a: 'I am also',
        b: 'another nested',
        c: 'object !!!',
      },
    }],
  }, {
    uid: '04a487c6-9624-4b2e-8411-59a69c14f1e3',
    secLevelProp1: 456,
    secLevelPropArr: [{
      uid: '58d4a3fd-734c-4c22-a0e3-f669e6ec7af3',
      thirdLevelProp1: 'another plain value',
    }],
  }],
};

The uid property values are unique for any given nested object (they are uuid v4 strings)
I also have an array of strings, describing a path to some nested property which looks like this:
const paths = [
  'topLevelProp2',
  '04a487c6-9624-4b2e-8411-59a69c14f1e3.secLevelProp1',
  'd7ed3623-e431-4bfa-85b3-8da14fa399c3.9394f313-b7bf-45fa-b8f3-683832ff7aa2.thirdLevelProp2.a',
  'd7ed3623-e431-4bfa-85b3-8da14fa399c3.9394f313-b7bf-45fa-b8f3-683832ff7aa2.thirdLevelProp2.c',
];

Instead of the keys of the array properties, the uid value of the contained object is used.
So the string'd7ed3623-e431-4bfa-85b3-8da14fa399c3.9394f313-b7bf-45fa-b8f3-683832ff7aa2.thirdLevelProp2.a' actually represents the path 'topLevelPropArr.0.secLevelPropArr.1.thirdLevelProp2.a' in the more usual path-in-object notation.
I want to filter my object in a way, so it will only contain (all nested) properties included in the array of paths.
Using the above example, filtering obj by paths would result in:
{
  topLevelProp2: 'data',
  topLevelPropArr: [{
    secLevelProp1: 456,
    secLevelPropArr: [{
      thirdLevelProp2: {
        a: 'I am also',
        c: 'object !!!',
      },
    }],
  }, {
    secLevelProp1: 456,
  }],
}

Keeping the order of items in the arrays is not necessary.
Here is the code I tried (honestly I think do not get the recursion right)
const SEPARATOR = '.';


const filterDataByPath = (originalData, path, filteredData = {}) => {

  const pathChunks = path.split(SEPARATOR);
  const currentChunk = pathChunks[0];

  // test whether there is a key in the current level of editData corresponding to the current chunk
  if (originalData.hasOwnProperty(currentChunk)) {
    // test whether the current value of the current valid key is an object
    if (typeof originalData[currentChunk] === 'object') {
      // recursively filter this object
      filteredData[currentChunk] = filterDataByPath(originalData[currentChunk], pathChunks.splice(1).join(SEPARATOR));
    } else {
      // take over the data value for the current key
      filteredData[currentChunk] = originalData[currentChunk];
    }
  } else { // find an array containing object with uid
    // and ist related key
    const [ key, val ] = Object.entries(originalData).reduce((keyArr, [ k, v ]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        // find the object with matching uid
        const targetrArray = v.find(obj => obj.uid === currentChunk);
        // if such object found returns it together with the key of the array storing it
        if (targetrArray) {
          return [ k, targetrArray ];
        }
      }
      return keyArr;
    }, []);

    // we found such an array
    if (key) {
      // create a new array in the filtered data under this particular key if not already present
      filteredData[key] = Array.isArray(filteredData[key]) ? filteredData[key] : [];

      filteredData[key].push(this.filterDataByPath(val, pathChunks.splice(1).join(SEPARATOR)));

      } else {
        // key not found - throw an exception, something is wrong with our path
        throw new Error(`Path not right, unknown chunk ${currentChunk}`);
      }

  }
  return filteredData;
}


let filteredData = {};
for (let index = 0; index < paths.length; index++) {
  filteredData = filterDataByPath(originalData, paths[index], filteredData)
};

The issue is, that the arrays in the filtered data have duplicate entries
BACKGROUND:
The data is bound to an Angular Template-Driven Form. Since there is still no support for FormArrayGroups in the Template-Driven Forms a possible workaround is declare a FormGroup and assign a unique key for a ngModelGroup
<fieldset *ngFor="let secLevelItem of data.topLevelPropArr;"
  [ngModelGroup]="secLevelItem.uid">

You could of course use index provided by the *ngFor but this does not work when you add/remove form fields on demand. Thus the solution with uid.
The paths are concatenated form-control names providing path to a particular dirty value - value which was changed in the form

please add your code. what goes wrong?

I added an example of my code. The issue is, the duplications of objects in arrays

speaking into the blue, you need to keep the refrence of the items with same uid. if reopened, i provide a solution.

That would be be a life-saving, I got stuck on it for days sadly

This solution take a recursive approach both for data and for paths. It take a check for a ke in the object, then for object or simple value or as uid in an array. If found, it take the substructure and the rest of the path.


const
    getData = (object, paths) => {
        const
            reference = {},
            order = new WeakMap,
            result = {},
            isOnlyObject = value => value && typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value),
            go = (source, target, [key, ...path]) => {
                if (key in source) {
                    const value = source[key];
                    if (isOnlyObject(value)) go(value, target[key] ??= {}, path);
                    else target[key] = value;
                    return;
                }
                for (const k in source) {
                    const v = source[k];
                    if (!Array.isArray(v)) continue;
                    const index = v.findIndex(({ uid }) => uid === key);
                    if (index === -1) continue;
                    if (!reference[key]) {
                        (target[k] ??= []).push(reference[key] = {});
                        order.set(reference[key], index);
                        target[k].sort((a, b) => order.get(a) - order.get(b));
                    }
                    if (path.length) go(v[index], reference[key], path);
                }
            };

        for (const path of paths) go(object, result, path.split('.'));
        
        return result;
    },
    data = { topLevelProp1: 'some', topLevelProp2: 'data', topLevelPropArr: [{ uid: 'd7ed3623-e431-4bfa-85b3-8da14fa399c3', secLevelProp1: 123, secLevelPropArr: [{ uid: '15562309-22b7-4b11-a12e-b3374f0a7636', thirdLevelProp1: 'a plain value', thirdLevelProp2: { a: 'I am', b: 'a nested', c: 'object' } }, { uid: '9394f313-b7bf-45fa-b8f3-683832ff7aa2', thirdLevelProp1: null, thirdLevelProp2: { a: 'I am also', b: 'another nested', c: 'object !!!' } }] }, { uid: '04a487c6-9624-4b2e-8411-59a69c14f1e3', secLevelProp1: 456, secLevelPropArr: [{ uid: '58d4a3fd-734c-4c22-a0e3-f669e6ec7af3', thirdLevelProp1: 'another plain value' }] }] }, 
    paths = ['topLevelProp2', '04a487c6-9624-4b2e-8411-59a69c14f1e3.secLevelProp1', 'd7ed3623-e431-4bfa-85b3-8da14fa399c3.9394f313-b7bf-45fa-b8f3-683832ff7aa2.thirdLevelProp2.a', 'd7ed3623-e431-4bfa-85b3-8da14fa399c3.9394f313-b7bf-45fa-b8f3-683832ff7aa2.thirdLevelProp2.c'];

console.log(getData(data, paths));
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




Awesome, thank you very much. Could you maybe explain the meaning of the target[key] ??= {} and target[k] ??= [] assignments ?
Is it current value or empty object/array ?

target[k] ??= [] means it assigns an array only if target[k] is null or undefined. see logical nullish assignment ??=

Thanks, also another question: what will happen, if one part of the path is for whatever reason corrupt/not fitting the data ? Will be a partial result returned ? In my original attempt I tried to target such a case by throwing an exception

it should work anyway. please try yourself.
